# Handling three while loops in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm new to PHP and struck with a while loop. Please throw some lights here.

I'm showing some information related to books vs author vs isbn number.

There are two tables: book and author. The book name and ISBN number comes from book table. The author name comes from author table.

Here is my poor php code(please dont laugh)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT book_name FROM book where status='1'")  or die(mysql_error());  
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT FName FROM author")  or die(mysql_error());  
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT book_isbn_number FROM book where status='1'")  or die(mysql_error());  
?>

<table style="margin-top:40px" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr style="background-color:#909F51">
        <td>Book List</td>

        <?php  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 )) {   ?>
        <td><?php echo $row1['book_name']; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>

<?php  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {   ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row2['author_name']; ?></td>

        <?php  while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {   ?>
            <td><?php echo $row3['book_isbn_number']; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

I'm not able to loop through the third while condition. I know the basic code structure is wrong.
Could someone help me out in getting the result.

### Tables:

## book

b_id

book_name

isbn_number

status

## author

a_id

author_name

Expected Output:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Author Name 1</td>
      <td>Author Name 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Book Name 1</td>
      <td>ISBN Number 1</td>
      <td>ISBN Number 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Book Name 2</td>
      <td>ISBN Number 3</td>
      <td>ISBN Number 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: show your tables structure and expected output. i think you have no need to use three loops

Comment: Why you are fetching different column from the same table `book` in query1 and query3? You can do it in single query.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan - please check my question again

Comment: @SatishSharma - please check my question agani

Comment: @user3326501 and what is the data in your tables `book` and `author`. i need it because your expected output difficult to understand the relation. explain more. so i can give you the answer according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$row3['isbn_number']` when the column you are selecting is "book_isbn_number". Try changing that line to be `<td><?php echo $row3['book_isbn_number']; ?></td>`. The loops themselves, while using the old, deprecated mysql_* functions, should be working fine.

Comment: typo. please check the question again, and the expected output i wish to have.. please

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><?php echo $row3['isbn_number']; ?></td>
```

replace it with

```
<td><?php echo $row3['book_isbn_number']; ?></td>
```

Comment: in your query you fetch `book_isbn_number` and print `isbn_number` so it did not match change it

Comment: please check the question again. its my spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT book_isbn_number FROM book where status='1'")  or die(mysql_error());
```

**Should be**

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT isbn_number FROM book where status='1'")  or die(mysql_error());**
```

**OR**

```
 <td><?php echo $row3['isbn_number']; ?></td>
```

**Should be**

```
<td><?php echo $row3['book_isbn_number']; ?></td>
```

Whichever fits your need